# VirtualBox abruptly stopped detecting USB devices

Tags: usb, virtualbox

After I first installed VirtualBox, I added my user to `vboxusers` group using `sudo adduser $USER vboxusers` command. After that, VirtualBox was able to view USB devices.

Today, all of a sudden it stopped detecting them. Removing and reinstalling VirtualBox didn't fix the issue. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Removing didn't fix, but purging did:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Note that this doesn't remove your virtual machines. Hence, it's safe to perform.

Also make sure that your user is still a a member of `vboxusers` by running

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest deleting the app then installing a newer version of Virtual Box.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox
```

Comment: Thanks for editing that